# Distinguishing topology from metrics

Tags: general-topology

I'm trying to understand a point my professor made distinguishing topologies from metrics. He wrote:

> Many natural topologies do not come from metrics. For example, on the space of bounded functions $f: X \to \mathbb{R}$) the uniform convergence topology ($f_n \to f$ iff $|\sup\limits_{x} |f_n (x) - f(x)\ \to 0$) comes from a metric ($d(f,g) = \sup\limits_{x} |f(x) - g(x)|$) but pointwise convergence ($f_n \to f$ iff $\forall x \in X$, $f_n (x) \to f(x)$) doesn't (product topology).

I assume product topology is another name for the pointwide-convergency topology, but someone please correct me if I'm wrong. The main thing Id on't understand is the differentiation between topology and metric. When I see "uniform convergence topology," I think of the topology induces by the above metric $d(f,g)$; the first parenthetical comment is less of a 'topology' than the definition of uniform convergence. It turns out those are equivalent since this topology is induced by a metric, but there's more to it a priori, and as a result I can't figure out what he meant by the pointwise-convergence topology, as again this seems like nothing more than the definition of pointwise convergence.

Can someone help me parse these?

Comment: Do you know the definition of a topology?

Comment: Yes: a subset of the power set of $X$ consisting of open sets satisfying three axioms (contains empty set and $X$, closure under unions and finite intersections).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A topology is a very "bare-bones" thing: it just provides a notion of *openness* (satisfying a few basic properties) for subsets of a given set $X$ of points. Notions like "straight line," "angle," and even "**distance**" are not built into a topology.

Now every metric $d$ on a set $X$ **induces** a topology $\tau_d$ on $X$: namely, $U$ is **open according to $\tau_d$** (or more snappily, $U\in\tau_d$ since a topology *literally is* the collection of sets it declares to be open) iff for each $u\in U$ there is some $\epsilon>0$ such that for all $v\in X$ with $d(v,u)<\epsilon$ we have $v\in U$. Note that we may have $\tau_{d_1}=\tau_{d_2}$ even if $d_1$ and $d_2$ are quite different metrics; coming up with some examples of this is a good exercise (think about $\mathbb{R}^2$). Topologies of the form $\tau_d$ for some metric $d$ are called **metrizable**, and the study of metrizability and its variants is an important topic within general topology.

The pointwise convergence topology $\tau_{pwc}$ is **not** metrizable: there is no metric $d$ on the set $Fn(X,\mathbb{R})$ of functions from $X$ to $\mathbb{R}$ such that $\tau_d=\tau_{pwc}$. Of course, $\tau_{pwc}$ is **motivated by metric ideas**, but it's not literally induced by a metric in the very specific sense of the above paragraph. This is a good exercise; if you don't buy it, first try to write down an explicit metric $d$ on $Fn(X,\mathbb{R})$ and then show that $\tau_d=\tau_{pwc}$. As the issues with this become clear, you'll see how to prove that $\tau_{pwc}$ is not in fact metrizable.

Comment: This is very helpful, thank you. The only other thing I'm having trouble with, though, is understanding exactly what the pointwise convergence topology is. It's a set of open sets, surely, but how does this relate to the definition of a sequence of functions converging pointwise (i.e., how do we know when something is 'open')?

Comment: @JeremyS A set $O$ of bounded functions is open in the pointwise topology iff for each $f \in O$ we can find finitely many points $F \subseteq X$ and some $r>0$ so that $\{g \in B(X,\Bbb R)\mid |g(x)-f(x)|< r \text{ for all } x \in F\} \subseteq O$. This is a standard way of describing a base for the pointwise topology. So the convergence property follows from that, but it’s not the way the topology (as a set of subsets) is defined.